# Service to validate if url has valid toplevel domain

Tags: dns

I'm seraching for a service where I can validate if a given url has a valid toplevel domain. Since the list of topleveldomain is constantly expanding using a txt file is not good soltion anymore, so I want to use a webservice preferable from [iana.org.](http://iana.org).
Also using a txt file doesn't get country-code top-level domains like "co.at" etc...

The best thing I have found so far is a list of toplevel domains from, but it isn't stated when it gets updated. (link: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't feed it straight URLs, the most obvious service to use to check for valid top-level domains is DNS itself. Just send a query to one of the root servers and see if the RCODE is NOERROR or NXDOMAIN.